# How to retrigger UITableView canMoveRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using canMoveRowAt() and moveRowAt() to show drag handles on my rows. Within canMoveRowAt I test a condition based on some of the row's data:

`... get reference to row data ...`

`return rowData.myCondition()`

This works fine when the table is first put into Edit mode. However while in Edit mode the data in the row can change (it's still the same row though). I'd like to retrigger canMoveRowAt to re-evaluate the condition and potentially change whether a drag handle is shown for the row.

So far I've managed to do this only by ending and restarting Edit mode. When I do that it clears the selections in the table, so I have to save and reapply them. This seems like a bit of a hack.

Is there a more elegant way of re-triggering canMoveRowAt to avoid this?

Comment: Do you call `reloadRows(at:)` when you change the data?

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately that resets the selections in the UITableView as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the end I just went for reloadRows(at:), saving and restoring the selections around this:

```
let savedSelections = vList.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []
vList.reloadRows(at: [dragHandleRowIndexPath], with: .automatic)
for indexPath in savedSelections {
    vList.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```